# What Causes DatabaseTransactionOutOfOrderException and how do I fix this?

Tags: commerce

I am working on plugin to Drupal Commerce, and I started getting this error:

```
DatabaseTransactionOutOfOrderException: in DatabaseConnection->rollback() (line 1058 of /Library/WebServer/Documents/includes/database/database.inc).
```

Can anyone shed some light on what this error means? If I install a fresh drupal and reinstall my plugin, is that likely to clear things up?

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using `db_transaction()` in your custom code?

Comment: No, I am not. I am using commerce_payment_transaction_new,commerce_payment_transaction_save and a few other calls from the commerce_payment.module

Comment: Any chance you can edit the code into the question? At a guess those functions are being used in way that's causing an overlap in transactions, then one fails and everything blows up. It's hard to say without seeing the code though

Comment: I can't post the code at this time -- Could the overlap be from prior orders? (this is a payment plugin) could it get out of sync that way?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the code that raises the error.

Comment: I'm getting it on a Commerce Kickstart site right now. Just a stab, but all I did that may have brought it about was installing a module commerce_coupon_fixed_amount or deleting an order. I suspect the latter, bc I am new to Commerce, and maybe *deleting* an order is not allowed? I get this error when trying to add to cart or viewing a product node while I have an active cart (from before the error came up!).

Comment: Did you have any luck fixing this?  Maybe you should try a fresh install and leave out commerce_coupon_fixed_amount so you can isolate the error.

Comment: I was getting this error because I was attempting to save a value that was too large to an integer field on a node. God only knows why I chose a value so large, but it was representative of a non-value. The values was this: 99999999999999999.

Answer (score 3):

The [DatabaseTransactionOutOfOrderException](https://api.drupal.org/DatabaseTransactionOutOfOrderException) exception is part of the [rollback()](https://api.drupal.org/DatabaseConnection::rollback) method ([DatabaseConnection](http://api.drupal.org/DatabaseConnection) class) and it is thrown when a rollback() resulted in other active transactions being rolled-back instead of rollback to correct earlier savepoint.

You may debug it checking the backtrace when this exception is thrown.

In example defining the following hook:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_watchdog().
 */
function foo_watchdog($log_entry) {
  if ($log_entry['type'] == 'php' && $log_entry['severity'] <= WATCHDOG_WARNING) {
    // Old school
    // var_dump(debug_backtrace()); // Optionally add: exit();

    // Devel: Log the backtrace into temporary file: drupal_debug.txt
    // Locate via: $ drush eval "echo file_directory_temp() . '/drupal_debug.txt'"
    function_exists('dd') && dd(debug_backtrace());
  }
}
```

Don't forget to install [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module (for `dd`) and clear the cache before testing it.

Then try to reproduce the problem and then check your /tmp/drupal_debug.txt debug file which should contain something like (section _drupal_exception_handler):

```
[function] => _drupal_exception_handler
[args] => Array
    (
        [0] => DatabaseTransactionOutOfOrderException Object
            (
                [file:protected] => /var/www/includes/database/database.inc
                [line:protected] => 1071
                [trace:Exception:private] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [file] => /var/www/includes/database/database.inc
                                [line] => 1933
                                [function] => rollback
                                [class] => DatabaseConnection
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [file] => /var/www/sites/all/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/order/includes/commerce_order.controller.inc
                                [line] => 123
                                [function] => rollback
                                [class] => DatabaseTransaction
                            )
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [file] => /var/www/sites/all/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/order/commerce_order.module
                                [line] => 734
                                [function] => save
                                [class] => CommerceOrderEntityController
                                [type] => ->
```

So based on the above example, you know that something goes wrong in commerce_order.module on line 734 during CommerceOrderEntity save.

If it's still not clear, other suggestion is to enable MySQL query logging and check the suspicious queries which are sent.